# Help troubleshooting diy battery charge/protect/step-up circuit

Tags: battery-charging, surface-mount, diy, over-voltage-protection, over-discharge

I am following the schematic below trying to put together the circuit for a battery charger with over/under voltage protection and 3.7 to 5v step up.
[image]
I have populated only the battery charger part of the ic, in case it does not work it should be easier to debug.

I expect when I plug in a 5v power supply with a 3.7v li-ion cell connected to the battery terminals that one of the leds would light up and some current will flow to the battery.

The result is, both leds are off and no current flows. I have a current reader connected between the powersupply and the ic.

One of these

[image]

I am not sure if the orientation of Q1 and U1 chips is correct, there is no marking on them.

Below how I soldered them.

[image]

Picture above is my 12th attempt to mount the smd components, I spent under 1s on each part on this attempt, I am confident I did not thermal damage the components.

I followed the direction of the text as a guide for the chip orientation, that being, text reads from left to right, for Q1 this means bottom left pin is pin 0 and top left pin is pin 0 for U1.

Reference img and link to the pcb layout below.

[image]
[PCB link](https://easyeda.com/editor#id=19d85904554e4ffea163c9be46c52993%7C3eef3a2c1cf7442cb1e20a74c08b0d97)

I don't see why the charger ic is not working. I think I followed the schematic correctly.

What series of steps should I take in order to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: I would: 1) make sure the toggle switch is **open** so that the DCDC is unconnected 2) connect the battery - directly to ground to bypass the battery protection 3) **Measure** all the voltages, is there 5 V at VCC of TP4056 ? 4) If the LEDs still do not light up, connect a short wire to ground then touch the TP4056 on pins 6 and then 7 with that ground, the LEDs should light up, if not you mounted them the wrong way. Oh and next time, don't use black soldermask, it looks good but seeing the traces is a pain.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks for your comment, indeed the leds were mounted in the wrong orientation. I remounted them and now when I plug the power supply the red led is on. However when I attach a battery, there is no charge current flowing. Looking at the bottom layer of the pcb, B- is conneted to Q1 and U1 bybassing the switch, so in theory there should be a charge despite the fact that the DCDC part of the ic is not populated with the components yet. The battery is at 3.8v, the overcharge protection kicks in at 4.2v, so there should be a charge going on. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Hi, I managed to get it to work, I replaced U1 and Q1 and I have a charging battery now. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, the leds were mounted in reverse and either the dual chan mosfet or the battery protection ic was damaged.

After remounting the leds and replacing both the mosfet and the battery protection ic now the charger works.